# How to assign to a property within a lambda expression?

Tags: python

I have a class that is similar to the following:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, enabled=False):
        self._event_listeners = []
        self._enabled = enabled
    
    def register_event_listener(self, event_listener):
        self._event_listeners.append(event_listener)

    @property
    def enabled(self):
        return self._enabled
    
    @enabled.setter
    def enabled(self, enabled):
        self._enabled = enabled
        for event_listener in self._event_listeners:
            event_listener(self)
```

Now, say I have two instances of `Foo` - `a` and `b`. I would like the `enabled` state of `b` to follow that of `a`. My initial approach was to do this:

```py
a.register_event_listener(lambda x, y=b: (y.enabled := x.enabled))
```

Where I immediately discovered that assignment expressions are not legal for properties. Is there any way to accomplish this without `setattr` ugliness?

Comment: Why not just use a regular function definition statement to create your function? In any case, you can use `setattr`, but that's ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have since discovered two solutions that don't require replacing the `lambda` with a `def`.

First, there is the obvious implementation:

```py
a.register_event_listener(lambda x, y=b: setattr(y, 'enabled', x.enabled))
```

Needless to say, I am not a fan of using `setattr` for statically-defined attributes. Luckily, I stumbled upon an alternative:

```py
a.register_event_listener(lambda x, y=b: type(y).enabled.fset(y, x.enabled))
```